# Ruby shorthand for update_all?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is there a shorthand way to write the equivalent of:

```
array.each do |element|
   element.update(element.foo => bar)
end
```

Basically, a shorthand replica and replacement for the `update_all` method

Comment: Yes the element is an object. I want to update an attribute for each object in the array. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a one-liner using curly-braces and shortening `element` to `e`. This is arguably easier to read.

```
array.each { |e| e.update(e.foo => bar) }
```

Comment: I want to avoid `update_all` entirely. It's breaking a lot of my specs when I upgrade to rails 4.